# WampServer: How to create a new MySql root password?

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I deleted all users from my MySql and got left out. How can I start from scratch? I tried removing the server and reinstalling but apperantly some file remained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the instructions provided here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

Your answer will be just log on to localhost/phpmyadmin

if it asked login detail just type root as user name and just enter and you will see :

above users tab click on that and you will see users overview :

Click on  Edit Privileges in last row of table  , then you will see global privileges
 check all , and go below  you will see Change password and there select change password

and type your password and click on go and you are done :